# Finding polynomial $f(x)$ from $f(1)$ and $f(f(1))$

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n$, where $a_i\ge0$

Given $f(1)=p$ and $f(f(1))=q$, we have to find $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $\dots$, $a_n$, where such $f(x)$ exists. Or we have to confirm if such $f(x)$ exists or if the polynomial is ambiguous e.g. for $p=1$ and $q=2$, no such $f(x)$ exists but for $p=1$ and $q=1$, $f(x)=1$, $f(x)=x^2$ both can be solution.

What should be my procedure?

Comment: Are you still thinking about this problem? Because I know the answer

Comment: [Here](https://brilliant.org/problems/mystery-polynomial/?group=fF7jHUpfJqR9&ref_id=858079&auto_login_key=94oQOq6xTK7yzxYCjcCMhiwFICDqqerFSnh9XdIMUs) is a similar problem. (You can try to guess the answer, but if you give up, there are solutions)

Answer (score 0):

$f(f(1))=f(p)=q=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+...+a_np^n\\p=a_0+a_1+a_2+..a_n$

$\bullet$ if $a_0=a_1=...a_n=1\\q=1+p+p^2+...+p^n=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p},p=n+1\\q=\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}-1}{n}\implies f(x)=1+x+x^2+...+x^n$

$\bullet$ 
if $a_0=a_1=...a_n=a\\q=a+ap+ap^2+...+ap^n=a\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p},p=a+1\\q=\dfrac{(a+1)^{n+1}-1}{a}\implies f(x)=a+ax+ax^2+...+ax^n,a\ge0$

Comment: we have found $p,q$ and coefficiens for wich this function exists although more distinct constants  are possible ...we have not considered such coefficients...we have looked at trivial cases

Comment: What if p=15 and q= 58115

Comment: Yes, we have looked only for trivial cases, how should the general approach be?

Comment: this is not possible,so we shud make sure n is integer

Comment: not sure about general case

Comment: nobody can answer it?